# How to pass solution of ParametricNDSolve to NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am taking here example ParametricNDSolveValue problem from documentation

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f''[t] + a f[t] == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, f[10], {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

It is true I can use FindRoot like that

```
FindRoot[pfun[a], {a, 1}]
```

However when using NSolve following output is produced

```
input: NSolve[{pfun[a] == 0 && 0.5 < a < 1.7}, a]

output: 
NSolve[{ParametricFunction[ <> ][a] == 0 && 0.5 < a < 1.7}, a, Reals]
```

How can I repair this code?

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 evalutes  `FindRoot[pfun[a], {a, 1}] (*{a -> 1.20903}*)`as expected

Comment: Indeed it does. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough - NSolve error is the main problem here

Answer (score 4):

Don't know why `NSolve` doesn't work.

Try

```
NMinimize[{1, pfun[a] == 0, 0.5 < a < 1.7}, a]
(*{1., {a -> 1.20902}}*)
```

or

```
FindInstance[pfun[a] == 0 && 0.5 < a < 1.7, a ]
(*{{a -> 1.20903}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `DiscretizeRegion` to find all the solutions in the interval ,for example `0<a<10`.

```
Clear[pfun, reg, dreg, result];
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f''[t] + a f[t] == 0, f[0] == 1, 
    f'[0] == 0}, f[10], {t, 0, 10}, {a}];

reg = ImplicitRegion[{pfun[a] == 0}, {a}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg, {0, 10}];
result = MeshPrimitives[dreg, 0][[;; , 1, 1]] // Sort
Plot[pfun[a], {a, 0, 10}, Mesh -> {result}, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

> `{0.024674, 0.222066, 0.61685, 1.20903, 1.99859, 2.98556, 4.16991, 5.55165, 7.13079, 8.90732, 10.8812, 15.4213}`

[image]